# R - Pander table width on html

Tags: html, r, markdown, pander

I'm having some problems to control the width of a table created by pander library in R markdown script.

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
library(pander)
pander(head(iris), style = 'rmarkdown')
```
````

When I knit the document to a html, the table has the widht of the document, like this:

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17M5v.png)

I would like to have a not so wide table, something like this:

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNYXo.png)

Is it possible?

Thank you,

Bruno

Comment: You need to use CSS to control the style of your HTML -- it's outside of the scope of markdown.

Comment: Thank you daroczig, I used css as you said and solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Using daroczig tip, I solve it by using a .css file with the instruction:

```
.table{
width: 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks daroczig